# Calendar month view is unresponsive on iOS 9

Tags: ios

On two phones that I have tested the month view in the Calendar app in iOS 9 is unresponsive or ignore taps. It seems like most of the time double tapping a day will open that day but sometimes (rarely) only single tapping a day will open that day. Is anyone else seeing this. Is there a workaround I can try before restoring my device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple fixed this issue with iOS 9.1. It is mentioned in the release notes.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a double tap is needed to select a single day when in month view. And there doesn't seem to be a way to change it back in settings :/